# JQuery promises and HTML form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-deferred

What happens if you have jQuery deferred objects outstanding when a form is submitted. Does it just cancel them when the new page is loaded? For example:

```
<form id="#theform" action="process.php">
<input type="text" name="text">
</form>

<script>
    var test = $.Deferred();

    somefunction(function () { 
        test.resolve(data);
    })

    test.done(function (data) { 
        dostuff(data); 
    });

    $('#theform').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you try to test it ? Maybe you will find the answer....

Comment: What is stopping your from running the code, and figuring it out yourself?